# Compiler optimization in c++

Tags: c++, optimization, runtime, compiler-optimization

I am trying to implement two classes A and B which contain data stored in std::unique_ptr container, and A could transform to B with some calculation. The class A and class B are shown as below. The input parameter of constructor in class B is designed passing a object A. In order to measure the run-time performance, I use std::chrono library, and add a function "print_construction_time" in class B to show construction time.

CPU: Intel® Core™ i7-6700HQ 2.6GHz

RAM: 16GB

OS: Windows 10 1909

IDE: Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.4.4

c/c++ optimization setting: Maximum Optimization (Favor Speed) (/O2)

```cpp
class A
{
public:
    A(int input_size, int input_value)              //  constructor
    {
        this->data = std::make_unique<int[]>(input_size);
        this->size = input_size;
        for (int loop_number = 0; loop_number < size; loop_number++) {
            data[loop_number] = input_value;
        }
    }
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> get_data()
    {
        //  deep copy
        auto return_data = std::make_unique<int[]>(size);
        for (int loop_number = 0; loop_number < size; loop_number++) {
            return_data[loop_number] = data[loop_number];
        }
        return return_data;
    }
    int get_size()
    {
        return this->size;
    }
private:
    int size;
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> data;
};
```

```cpp
class B
{
public:
    B(A &input_object)                              //  constructor
    {
        this->size = input_object.get_size();
        this->data = std::make_unique<int[]>(this->size);
        this->start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        //  version 1
        for (int loop_number = 0; loop_number < input_object.get_size(); loop_number++) {
            this->data[loop_number] = transform_from_A(input_object.get_data()[loop_number]);
        }
        this->stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();  //  for execution time measurement
    }
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> get_data()
    {
        //  deep copy
        auto return_data = std::make_unique<int[]>(size);
        for (int loop_number = 0; loop_number < size; loop_number++) {
            return_data[loop_number] = data[loop_number];
        }
        return return_data;
    }
    void print_construction_time()
    {
        auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(stop - start);
        std::cout << "Duration: " << duration.count() << "microseconds" << std::endl;
    }
private:
    int size;
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> data;
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> start, stop;
    int transform_from_A(int input_value)
    {
        return input_value + 1; // For example
    }
};
```

The main function is here.

```cpp
int main()
{
    A a_object(10000, 6);
    B b_object(a_object);
    b_object.print_construction_time();

    return 0;
}
```

For testing, I run this code three times and the execution time is 123407us, 112033us and 107586us.
Next, I modify the for loop block in the constructor of class B into version 2 which designed with cached data.

```cpp
        //  version 2   <=  tremendously faster than version 1
        auto data_cached = input_object.get_data();
        for (int loop_number = 0; loop_number < input_object.get_size(); loop_number++) {
            this->data[loop_number] = transform_from_A(data_cached[loop_number]);
        }
```

The measurement result of version 2 is 27us, 32us and 43us. I am curious that why the compiler seems not perform the Maximum Optimization in speed automatically through cache tricks based on the condition of the same calculation result and it need to be done by human. I think that this kind of optimization maybe could be done either by compiler automatically or by popping up the modify suggestion in editor environment.

Note: I also modify the optimization setting for testing. The run-time performance is similar between optimization setting in Maximum Optimization (Favor Speed) (/O2) and Optimizations (Favor Speed) (/Ox).

**Feb. 27. 2020 Update**

I also tried to modify the return type of A::get_data() in class A with adding `const` keyword of std::unique_ptr.

```cpp
    const std::unique_ptr<int[]> get_data()    //    <= Add const keyword of std::unique_ptr
    {
        //  deep copy
        auto return_data = std::make_unique<int[]>(size);
        for (int loop_number = 0; loop_number < size; loop_number++) {
            return_data[loop_number] = data[loop_number];
        }
        return return_data;
    }
```

The measurement result of execution time is as similar as above. They are 101486us, 100538us and 120620us in version 1 and 55us, 30us and 27us in version 2. The optimization setting is Optimizations (Favor Speed) (/Ox) and IDE is updated to Version 16.4.5 .

Moreover, the case of "both const" (not only std::unique_ptr but its content), that is `const std::unique_ptr<const int[]>` also be considered.

```cpp
    const std::unique_ptr<const int[]> get_data()
    {
        //  deep copy
        auto return_data = std::make_unique<int[]>(size);
        for (int loop_number = 0; loop_number < size; loop_number++) {
            return_data[loop_number] = data[loop_number];
        }
        return return_data;
    }
```

The measurement result of execution time is also as similar as above. They are 114754us, 127327us and 106122us in version 1 and 32us, 34us, and 44us in version 2. The optimization setting is also Optimizations (Favor Speed) (/Ox).

Comment: So you are asking why the compiler doesn't eliminate all of the copying in `A::get_data`?

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you for your prompt reply. I am curious about why the compiler doesn't estimate iterating of all of the copying in `A::get_data` is needed or not.

Comment: You've tripped over something interesting here: `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> start, stop;` defines with `steady_clock` but `this->start = high_resolution_clock::now();` assigns `high_resolution_clock`. Looks like `high_resolution_clock` is `steady_clock` in the MSVC Standard library.

Comment: I'm not the man to answer that one, it seems. The only sort-of observable behaviour I see is the memory consumption, but clearly the compiler's not making the leap to caching.

Comment: @user4581301 In the run-time performance measure part, I refer to https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/measure-execution-time-function-cpp/ about using chrono library. The type of provided example is using auto keyword. The IntelliSense in Visual Studio shows the type is steady_clock.

Comment: I knew the standard library could play games with exactly what backed the high resolution clock, but I'd never seen so obvious a demonstration so I'd never given it much thought. Then I tried to compile the code in GCC and the compiler started howling over type mis-matches.

Comment: Sidenote: You have to be a bit more careful with the cut and pasting. The code is a bit confused. Sometimes it's using fully-qualified names and sometimes it's leaving out the namespaces. Makes for a somewhat odd-looking read.

Comment: GCC and Clang don't seem to pick up on this at O2 either.

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you for notifying. I have modified the code to fully-qualified names.

Comment: Why would you expect the compiler to notice that your (non-const!) method happens to have no side effects so that the allocations can all be merged?  Is there some simpler case where such an optimization *does* happen?

Comment: @DavisHerring Thanks for your response. As your consideration, it may be not appropriate to generate cache automatically in "non-const" condition. I also tried the "const" case and update the question.